# Why is the processor limit in VMware player lower than the number of physical cores on my CPU?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-player, multi-processor

My CPU has 18 cores, and, due to hyperthreading, 36 logical processors. However, VMware player's highest option in settings is a 16 processor virtual machine. Is there a reason for this? I have tried Googling, but have been able to find no answer. This is frustrating, as I would like to bring all my computational resources to bear.

I am on a Windows 10 host, using VMware Workstation 12 player to virtualize Ubuntu 16.04, and I have a Xeon E5-2697 v4.

Comment: Have you contacted VMWare about this question, this sounds like a software limit, what your configuration file look like.  If you manually within the configuration file, set it to 18 does it detect 18?  Verify your using hardware version 12 not 11 or lower

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the capabilities of [VMWare Workstation 12 Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player.html):

> Support for up to 16 vCPUs, 8TB disks, 64 GB of RAM, and 2GB Video RAM

According to that, you won't be able to get more than 16 virtual cores running. You may want to look at more advanced offerings.

Comment: You would have to go to thier server based products more then likely to get the ability to assign more then 16 cores to a VM